# Subtract two numeric column values in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to subtract two column values and display the output column in select query.

```
SELECT c.name,
    (SELECT SUM(p.qty*s.price)
     FROM stock s, purchase p 
     WHERE s.company = p.company 
     GROUP BY p.company) 
 MINUS 
    (SELECT SUM(p.price*p.qty) 
     FROM stock s, purchase p 
     WHERE s.company = p.company 
     GROUP BY p.company)  AS "Profit/Lost" 
 FROM purchase p, client c, stock s 
 WHERE  s.company = p.company 
     AND c.clno = p.clno  
 GROUP BY p.company;
```

But it will display an error. How to solve?

Comment: There are so many problems with your query that there is no place to begin.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are confusing what `minus` does; it removes groups of rows; sounds like you just need an arithmatic `-` for the two columns.  But Gordon is right; we need sample data and sample desired output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First subquery needs an Alias.

but why use subquery at all? 
Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.name, p.company,
   SUM(p.qty*s.price) - SUM(p.price*p.qty) roe
FROM client c
   join purchase p on p.clno  = c.clno 
   join stock s on s.company = p.company 
GROUP BY c.name, p.company;
```

Comment: Thanks. Something similar to that.